# Can the D3 brane be described by M theory?

Tags: string-theory, branes

M theory has only 2 fundamental objects, the M2 and M5 brane. These can describe a variety of different branes. However, is there any description on how M theory describes D3 branes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $D_3$-brane in type IIb string theory corresponds to an M5-brane wrapped on a "IIa/IIb" torus $T^2 = S_A^1\times S_B^1$ in M-theory on $\mathbb{R}^{1,8}\times T^2$, i.e. you obtain the $D_3$-brane from the M5-brane by first going from M-theory to type IIa string theory and then using T-duality to go to type IIb string theory.